# Print spacing in Python

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is it possible to print multiple strings on one line in such a way that the final string will always be x amount of space from the left? For example, is there anyway to print a result similar to this, where strZ is always printed in the same place (not right-justified)?

```
strA strB strC        strZ 
strA                  strZ 
strC StrB strD strE   strZ
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

```
fmt = '{:<4} {:<4} {:<4} {:<6} {:<4}'
print(fmt.format('strA', 'strB', 'strC', '', 'strZ'))
print(fmt.format('strA', '', '', '', 'strZ'))
print(fmt.format('strA', 'strB', 'strC', 'strE', 'strZ'))
```

prints

```
strA strB strC        strZ
strA                  strZ
strA strB strC strE   strZ
```

See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).